JSONSET using Spring Data redis
Currently I am using Jedis directly in my springboot application to do the JSON partial updates using JSONSET in Jedis. Does spring data redis provides support for this using Jedis?

spring data redis doesn't provide such support. Doesn't matter if using Jedis or not.
